# Network-manager restart just stopped

Tags: dns

So I changed my dns to googles 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Saved and service network-manager restart never restarted
It looks like it want to pop up but doesnt

I also tried

```
 systemctl restart network-manager service
 nmcli networking off
 nmcli networking on
 ifconfig wlan0 down
 ifconfig wlan0 up
 service network-manager force-reload
```

When I re-entered /etc/resolv.conf it was completely empty so I added my dns and tried a restart but nothing, I know you can restart your computer 
And everything would reset itself, but is there a fix to this manually

My network interfaces look like this

```
auto lo
allow-hotplug eth0
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

And my connectivity with the networking

```
fmcli networking connectivity
full
```

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this error by going to the

```
nano /etc/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf
```

And changing the false to true and changed

```
nano /etc/networkmanager/systemconnections/my wifi

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

Then did a ifconfig cause I was previously was running  a vpn with a Google 8.8.8.8 - 8.8.4.4 nameserver 
And I had this

```
 eth0

 Lo: active

 Tun0: active

 Wlan0: active
```

The thing is, it said I had a internet connection but I wasn't getting a connection to any webpages.
This was the main problem !

```
Ifconfig tun0 down
```

Then I ran the

```
service network-manager restart
```

I ran this just for precautions

```
apt-get install nscd
/etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

The name service cache daemon